# On Windows 10 Django is not installing properly under the project folder - unable to find manage.py

Tags: django, windows-10, manage.py

I am a new developer. I'm following instructions from to Django for Beginners book.

When I run

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\HelloWorld>pipenv install django~=3.1.0
```

The message I got:

```
Installation Succeeded
```

However when I typed into the console, I got the following result:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\HelloWorld>pipenv shell
(User-jBUq-HwN) C:\Users\User>
```

However, in the book the result looks like:

```
(helloworld) $
```

And according to the book on page 34, when I try to run the server, the following error occurs

```
(User-jBUq-HwN) C:\Users\User\Desktop\HelloWorld>python manage.py runserver
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any reasons why it can't find manage.py?

Answer (score 1):

After installing django to activate the environment:

```
pipenv shell
```